# FluentAssertions - "nested" Exclude

Tags: c#, testing, fluent-assertions

I have an API providing tons of functionality, thatswhy there are massive abstractions to generics.

Please imagine (with the code below) following scenario: Every `Dto` has an `Id`. I want to test against a Service, create the items. The service doenst know the `Id`, because it gets generated by the `DbContext`.
So far so regualar.

But now imagine, i have a nested `Dto`, like in the example `ComplexDto` contains a `SampleDto`. So my `TestHelper` should test all the `IDto`, and ignore ALL `Ids` (the one of `ComplexDto` AND `SampleDto`), just by having the Interface.

DTO-Setup:

```cs
public interface IDto
{
    long Id { get; }
}

public abstract record BaseDto : IDto
{
    public long Id { get; init; }
}

public sealed record SampleDto : BaseDto
{
    public string FooString { get; init; } = string.Empty;
}

public sealed record ComplexDto : BaseDto
{
    public string AnotherFooString { get; init; } = string.Empty;

    public SampleDto SampleDto { get; init; } = default!;
}
```

Test-Setup

```cs
[Test]
public void TestDummy()
{
    var dto = new ComplexDto()
    {
        Id = 1, // for demo porposes
        SampleDto = new SampleDto
        {
            Id = 1, // for demo porposes
            FooString = "hi"
        }
    };

    var testHelper = new TestHelper<ComplexDto>();

    testHelper.CheckStuff(dto);
}

public class TestHelper<IDto>
{
    public void CheckStuff(IDto dto)
    {
        var anotherDto = new ComplexDto()
        {
            Id = 123, // for demo porposes
            SampleDto = new SampleDto
            {
                Id = 123, // for demo porposes
                FooString = "hi"
            }
        };

        //fails
        //ComplexDto.Id gets ignored
        //SampleDto.Id does not get ignored!!!
        anotherDto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(dto, options => options.Excluding(x => x.Id));
    }
}
```

So actually, what i am looking for, is in FluentAssertions-Api something like `ExcludeAll("Id")` or `ExcludeRecursive("Id")`. I could help myself with some ugly reflection, but maybe there is a "good" solution for this?

Help is appreciated <3

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any solution yet. Instead of "ignoring" the test-values, i went with "improved" seeding for the IDs.

Really hard, by setting them in a generic way with SpecimenBuilders (in AutoFixture), but anyhow it works.